# Nodejs Express 4 routes not working after changing server to https

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ssl, express, https

I'm using the mean stack (angular v1.4.7, node v0.12.7, express 4.9.0) for my project.

Recently, i adquire ssl certificates and install them on the server, so i had to change my http requests to https.

I also change the nodejs server to requires https instead of the http, but **the express routes stopped working** and every request is returning **net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**. Here is some examples:

Request on angularjs:

```
$http({
    url: "https://www.urbs.pt:3000/auth/isauth",
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.isloggedin = data;

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(config);
});
```

I'm running my nodejs server with express on port 3000 using https

```
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate');

var options = {
  key:    fs.readFileSync(pathtokey),
  cert:   fs.readFileSync(pathtocertificate),
  ca:     fs.readFileSync(pathtoCA),
  requestCert:        true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var app = express();
var https = require('https').Server(options,app);

/* this part is initialized on bin/www
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
*/  

app.use('/auth', authenticate);
```

If i use http protocol on the angularjs request, and require http on nodejs everything is working as expected, so i guess that the problem is with the https request. I also confirmed that the options configurations are correct.

Comment: what is the error ? do you see any failed request? check if maybe you are requesting library with http in your htmls script tags

Comment: i would suggest not to use https on nodejs in production, you can use nginx or apache as reverse proxy with https. node is single threaded, its not optimized for heavy computing involved with https.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  Ashok Kumar Sahoo, i've done some research, and i'm following your advise. I've put nginx as a reverse proxy and to serve my static content. Right now the problem i'm having is implementing nginx and socket.io over https. Thank you for putting me on the right track.